# Finding the index of a character in an item in a list - Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to find the index of a character of an item in a list. For example:

```
list = ['hello','how','are','you']
```

How would I write some code that returns the "o" from 'hello', or the "r" from 'are', for example?

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: The question is vague - you've given two examples of outputs but not said what the corresponding inputs would be, or why.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I've tried doing things like list[0], which just returns 'hello', and then things such as list[0[1]] or list[0:1], which also haven't given what I need. I'm really at a loss. Also apologies, I'm new to stack overflow.

Comment: Welcome to SO - your question is being downvoted because it appears very low-effort and along the lines of "please give me the answer to my verbatim homework assignment"! It's great to put some information about what you've tried in your question, so we can better help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reference a specific member, `list[0][1]` could be what you're looking for.

```py
>>> list_of_words = ['hello','how','are','you']
>>> list_of_words[0][4]
'o'
```

---

If you're trying to find a specific character, you could iterate over your list and *then* iterate again over each member of the list to see if you've found your character

```py
for word in words:
    for letter in word:
        # do comparison here
```

To find the number of the index, you can wrap your iteration in [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get a tuple of both the value and its index

```py
for index, word in enumerate(words):
    ...
```

Also as a note for later, it's better not to name your list `list`, but something more descriptive, such as `list_of_words`, as it steps on the class (this means if you declared a `list()` in the same scope, it will try to reference your variable instead of the builtin)